# R - gsub - replace character exact match

Tags: r, gsub

I am using the following code to replace string characters with empty strings:

```
description_clean_df$description_clean <- gsub("amp", "", description_clean_df$description_clean)
```

How can I have this as exact match? E.g. I want to replace exactly "amp", but not other words which contain "amp", such as the word "example"? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the wordboundary (`\\b`) before and after the word 'amp' so that it won't match any words with a substring 'amp' in it

```
description_clean_df$description_clean <- gsub("\\bamp\\b", "", 
    description_clean_df$description_clean)
```

Comment: Does this replace the exact match word "amp" with the empty string?

Comment: @adrCoder based on this example `description_clean_df <- data.frame(description_clean = c('hello amp ddssds', 'example amp sesee'))`, i find it replacing